# Python Selenium Click button

Tags: python, selenium, button

I am trying to use Selenium to click the add to basket button as shown in the code below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#Lauch Chrome driver
b = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
b.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing/laptops/laptops/asus-vivobook-k403ja-14-laptop-intel-core-i5-512-gb-ssd-silver-blue-10208166-pdt.html")

b.find_element_by_class_name("Button__StyledButton-iESSlv").click()
```

However, I got the error below saying the element is not clickable:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" class="Button__StyledButton-iESSlv iQXRSE Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy">...</button> is not clickable at point (857, 60). Other element would receive the click: <div class="onetrust-pc-dark-filter ot-fade-in" style="z-index:2147483645"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Anyone has any idea why that's the case?

Comment: I just saw this website and I noticed that there are 14 elements with that class, try to search the element by XPath (absolute path). Just check if it works with XPath, if you tell me what button it is I can try to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Add to basket')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Remove the popup and click the add to basket button.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```